# "Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration" with two dimensions, despite having matchingFallbacks

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I know this is a commonly asked question, but nothing seems to apply to this problem.

I have an Android project and a bunch of libraries it depends on. The project has a dimension, "env", which can be "mock", "debug", "release". The library has the same dimension, but only "debug" or "release". "mock" has a fallback on "debug".

Here's a simplified setup:

App's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
        staging {
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'env'

    productFlavors {
        mock {
            dimension 'env'
            matchingFallbacks = ['dev']
        }
        dev {
            dimension 'env'
        }
        prod {
            dimension 'env'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        dev {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/live/java', 'src/dev/java']
        }
        staging {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/live/java', 'src/staging/java']
        }
        prod {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/live/java', 'src/prod/java']
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/mock/java', 'src/androidTest/java']
        }
        androidTestMockDebug {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/mock/java', 'src/androidTest/java']
        }
    }
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':myLibrary:myLibrary')
```

The library is in the subdirectory `myLibrary/myLibrary`, there's also a `myLibrary/sample` that I don't want to include in the app.

Library's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'env'

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension 'env'
        }
        prod {
            dimension 'env'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

I'm getting this error when I try to build something as mockDebug (this is an excerpt, the full error is very long):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myApp:hiltJavaCompileMockDebug'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':myApp:hiltCompileOnlyMockDebug'.
   > Could not resolve project :myLibrary:myLibrary.
     Required by:
         project :myApp
      > No matching variant of project :myLibrary:myLibrary was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'env' with value 'mock' but:
          - Variant 'devDebugApiElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'dev' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'devDebugRuntimeElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'dev' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'devReleaseApiElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'env' with value 'dev' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'devReleaseRuntimeElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'env' with value 'dev' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'prodDebugApiElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'prod' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'prodDebugRuntimeElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'prod' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'prodReleaseApiElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'env' with value 'prod' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
          - Variant 'prodReleaseRuntimeElements' capability myApp.myLibrary:myLibrary:unspecified declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'env' with value 'prod' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'env' with value 'mock'
```

This all works fine if I compile in `devDebug`, but these errors here show up when I compile in `mockDebug`.

Comment: Do you have any `:myLibrary` dependency ? can you post full gradle file .

Comment: @Manohar I do. The full build files are too large to add here, but I added more relevant parts.

Comment: `(path: ':myLibrary:myLibrary')` looks suspicious, may be it should just be `(path: ':myLibrary')`

Comment: @Manohar It's a subdirectory. myLibrary is a project that contains a sample, and myLibrary:myLibrary is the subdirectory that contains the actual library.

Comment: Did you include path  in `settings.gradle`

Comment: @Manohar I did, yes. `include ':myLibrary:myLibrary'`. And it compiles in `devDebug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Gradle.

I have this problem in `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2` (any 7.1.* version really) and the 7.2 beta versions. Going back to `7.0.4` fixes the problem.